# wp-config.php file and code injection

Tags: security, wp-config

It looks like several my sites on BlueHost got code injection in the wp-config.php file. Injected code itself looks [like](http://pastebin.com/rb5HzYnh)

Any clue where it comes from? BH malware scan doesn't recognize that code so they are not able to detect where it started.

Thanks

Comment: Have you contacted [Bluehost support](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/ticket) about this issue? what do they say?

Comment: Yes, I spoke to them, they have scanned whole account and told me that they scan for known malware code and may not recognize whatever they don't have in their database.

Comment: Usually encrypted code like this are some kind of malware. You will need to decrypt it to know where it comes from. Unfortunately not a field I have knowledge about.